# How to fix "Can't install XYZ app" error on Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

[image: Download error on Google Play store]

I'm getting this dialog when downloading an app/game. How do I fix it?

Dialog content:

> **Can't install Fish Paradise - Ocean Friends.**
>
> Try again, and if it still doesn't work, [see common ways to fix the problem](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7513003?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

there are several possible reasons for that.

1. your android version isn't compatible to this app
2. your device misses a feature or a library that is required by the app
3. you have no enough space for the app to be installed
4. the app has some kind of bug (this way, you can leave a review or contact app developers if the question is important)